# What is this sign ↵ and why NodeJs convert all my \n to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I save in the DB(mongodb) a string with line brakes, it's seems like the DB return the string as i expected (with the \n).

But when I send it back to the client, the string return with this ENTER sign (↵).